# Which is the correct numbering of locants for ethyldimethylcyclohexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Can anyone kindly help me to name this compound?

[image]

Is the above compound **3-Ethyl-1,1-dimethylcyclohexane** or **1-Ethyl-3,3-dimethylcyclohexane**?

Comment: Related: [Nomenclature of ether and locant position enumeration](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33122/7951)

Answer (score 0):

3-Ethyl-1,1-dimethylcyclohexane

Following the IUPAC rules, the correct name will have the lowest numbers for the substituents. Therefore, 1,1, and 3 is lower than 3,3 and 1.