# Nomenclature of alkoxy and halo groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

CH<sub>3</sub>-O-CH<sub>2</sub>CH<sub>2</sub>Cl

How will this compound be named? Both, methoxy and chloro are given equal preference, since they are prefix functional groups. The answer given in the book is 2-chloro-1-methoxyethane, but why is it not 1-chloro-2-methoxyethane, as the C of chlorine comes before M in the alphabetical order?

Comment: This is rather weird. I was expecting your suggestion to be correct.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani Are you sure there's no order of preference for prefix functional groups?

Comment: It might be that there is an order of preference after all. According to the following link, ethers have a priority over halo groups: http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/02/14/table-of-functional-group-priorities-for-nomenclature/

Comment: @AnthonyKelesidis Well, I am quite sure there is no order of preference here. Refer to the answer by to this question of mine : http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33122/nomenclature-of-ether-and-locant-position-enumeration .
It makes complete sense, and also gives me the correct answer.

Comment: According to the IUPAC name generator at http://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/iupac-naming, the "correct" name is "1-Chloro-2-methoxyethane".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Your name, 1-chloro-2-methoxyethane, is correct.

Here is a link to the relevant page of the 1993 edition of the [IUPAC Blue Book - Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_430.htm), which is published online by ACD Labs with permission of IUPAC.

Here are some example ethers and sulfides from that page, and we see a similar case to yours:

[image: example IUPAC ether nomenclature]

There is no difference in preference or priority between `halo` and `alkoxy` substituents (or any of the other prefix only substituents). Thus, in a case where there are two such groups and assignment of locants generates the same combination either way, you choose to assign the lower locant number to the [alphabetically first](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_317.htm).

Comment: Please be aware, that there is a [new version of the blue book from 2013](http://www.rsc.org/shop/books/2013/9780854041824.asp) and we have already had some questions, where there were significant differences. However, in that case I believe the rule still holds.

Answer (score 2):

The current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.5** ALPHANUMERICAL ORDER
>
> Alphanumerical order has been commonly called ‘alphabetical order’. As these ordering principles do involve ordering both letters and numbers, in a strict sense, it is best called ‘alphanumerical order’ in order to convey the message that both letters and numbers are involved
>
> Alphanumerical order is used to establish the order of citation of detachable substituent prefixes (not the detachable saturation prefixes, hydro and dehydro), and the numbering of a chain, ring, or ring system when a choice is possible.
>
> (…)
>
> **P-14.5.1** Simple prefixes (i.e., those describing atoms and unsubstituted substituents) are arranged alphabetically; multiplicative prefixes, if necessary, are then inserted and do not alter the alphabetical order already established.

Therefore, the correct alphanumerical order of citation in your example corresponds to the name ‘*x*-chloro-*y*-methoxyethane’.

Furthermore,

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

Note that Rule f takes precedence over Rule g.
According to Rule f, the name of the given compound could be ‘1-chloro-2-methoxyethane’ as well as ‘2-chloro-1-methoxyethane’ since both names correspond to the locant set ‘1,2’ (all prefixes considered together in a series of increasing numerical order).
According to Rule g, however, the compound is named as ‘1-chloro-2-methoxyethane’ rather than ‘2-chloro-1-methoxyethane’ since ‘chloro’ is cited first as a prefix in the name.

[image: 1-chloro-2-methoxyethane]

Comment: So, you mean the book is wrong?

Comment: @ag_dhruv The name “2-chloro-1-methoxyethane” given in your book is wrong in so far as it is not the preferred IUPAC name; it is not even a valid name for general (IUPAC) nomenclature. Nevertheless, this name is unambiguous, and interpretation of this name would yield the correct compound. Therefore, it is not completely wrong.